# Localize js not translating date in react app

Tags: reactjs, localization

I am working on translating the content to Korean, while the translation of dates is working fine in Angular App using localize JS, same is not working in React App, while everything else, just works fine and LocalizeJS is doing well. I have tried using `<var>` for the same but didn't help.

Do I need to use any other library on top of localizing js?

Comment: Adding what you tried here (in code) would help a lot in finding a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was with moment.js which needs to translate the date and to do so we need to set the language, whenever we switching language for localizejs set it for moment as well.

```
Localize.setLanguage(switch_to_lang.name); // setting language for LocalizeJS
moment.locale(switch_to_lang.name) // setting language for moment
```